# Getting exception NoClassDefFoundError when connecting to Redis with lettuce 6.0.1

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

I'm new to java. Trying to connect to Redis with Lettuce.
Environment: openjdk - 15.0.1, Lettuce-core-6.0.1. RELEASE, Redis instance launched on RedisLabs (free tier), Dependency management as java Plain. IDE: IttelijIDEA.

I wrote this program code bellow, and when building its raises an Exception. Kindly asking for any suggestions how that could be fixed? Thanks a lot in advance to provided assistance.

```
import io.lettuce.core.RedisClient;
import io.lettuce.core.api.StatefulRedisConnection;
import io.lettuce.core.api.sync.RedisCommands;


public class redisConnect {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("I remember how to create simple java program :)");
        System.out.println("with this program I will connect to REDIS instance on ReidsLabs");

        RedisClient redisClient = RedisClient.create("redis://password@host-name-from-redisLabs:port/dbname");
        try (StatefulRedisConnection<String, String> connection = redisClient.connect()) {
            RedisCommands<String, String> syncCommands = connection.sync();

            syncCommands.set("key", "Hello, Redis!");
            String str = syncCommands.get("key");
            System.out.println(str);

            connection.close();
        }
        redisClient.shutdown();

    }
}
```

Exception value:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/netty/channel/group/ChannelGroup
    at redisConnect.main(redisConnect.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.netty.channel.group.ChannelGroup
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:606)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:168)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
    ... 1 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Lettuce Client has been uploaded from here: https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/releases/download/6.0.1.RELEASE/lettuce-core-6.0.1.RELEASE-bin.zip
Code example has been taken from here: https://lettuce.io/core/6.0.1.RELEASE/reference/#getting-started.plain-java
Dependency to the project in intellij has been imported: like that:

[image: lettuce-dependency-to-project]

Comment: I posted this: https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/discussions/1614

Comment: On a different topic : I would suggest moving to having a "framework" for these imported libraries, instead of doing them by hand.  I much prefer gradle (build.gradle and settings.gradle) over maven pom.xml files.  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.lettuce/lettuce-core/5.3.6.RELEASE. intellij can work with this very easily.  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.lettuce/lettuce-core
implementation group: 'io.lettuce', name: 'lettuce-core', version: '5.3.6.RELEASE'